# Alignment column and line chart with the same data (highcharts)

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have a problem with an alignment two separated charts which are placed one after another. Both charts are basing on the same data, but their xAxis are displaying a little different.

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/4p7cbaje/1/

```
$(function () {

    var point = 5;
    var d = [[1, 50], [2, 100], [3.7, 30], [8, 60], [9,20], [10, 50], [12, 100], [14.7, 30], [17, 60], [19,20]];
    var min = 1;
    var max = 19;

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart : {
            type: 'column'  
        },
        title: null,
        credits: false,
        legend: { enabled: false },
        xAxis: {
            min: min,
            max: max,
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#FF0000',
                width: 2,
                value: point
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            data: d
        }]
    });

    $('#container2').highcharts({
        chart : {
            type: 'line'  
        },
        title: null,
        legend: { enabled: false },
        xAxis: {
            min: min,
            max: max,
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#FF0000',
                width: 2,
                value: point
            }]
        },

        series: [{
            data: d
        }]
    });

});
```

The vertical lines (red plotLines) should be coincide with each other. 
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Set `pointRange` for both charts to be the same: http://jsfiddle.net/4p7cbaje/2/ - column range works a bit different, as you can see.